# Underbrace in Matrix without array package

Tags: matrices, arrays, underbrace, overbrace

I've been struggling with matrix underbrace, and I can't find any way through all LaTeX questions about how to use an underbrace in a matrix without the array package.

So far I got here, with these new commands, but the underbrace/overbrace is not correctly placed in the second matrix.

## MWE

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath, amssymb, etoolbox}


\newcommand\aug{\fboxsep=-\fboxrule\!\!\!\fbox{\strut}\!\!\!}

\newcommand\undermat[2]
    {\makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\underbrace{\phantom{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}_{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}
\newcommand\overmat[2]{
  \makebox[0pt][l]{$\smash{\overbrace{\phantom{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}}^{\text{$#1$}}}$}#2}

\begin{document}

$$\begin{pmatrix}
    2 & 3 & 1 & \aug & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 & \aug & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
   \undermat{A}{ 5 & 4 & 6 } & \aug & \undermat{I}{ 0 & 0 & 0 }\\
\end{pmatrix}
\xrightarrow[\rm{Jordan}]{\rm{Gauss}}
\begin{pmatrix}
    \overmat{I}{ 1 & 0 & 0 }& \aug & \overmat{A^{-1}}{ 4/7 & 2 & -3/7 }\\
    0 & 1 & 0 & \aug & 1/7 & -1 & 1/7 \\
    0 & 0 & 1 & \aug & -4/7 & -1 & 3/7 \\
\end{pmatrix}$$



\end{document}
```

[image]

In the second matrix, if I use `\undermat{}{}` it gives the same result.

Comment: why not array package (it is part of core latex, unlike say etoolbox which you are using) (I don't think it would help much here, it just seems a strange requirement in your question. The only reason array is not pre-loaded in the format is memory requirements on PCs in 1993

Comment: `\rm` is not defined by default in latex, but where it is defined for compatibility with pre-1993 documents, the syntax is `{\rm Jordan}]`  not `\rm{Jordan}` it did not take an argument.

Comment: I forgot, i renamed the command `\textrm` to `\rm` to make it faster. I don't like the array package because I got a lot of trouble with incompatibilites with the xltabular package and a bunch others.

Comment: that's a pretty bad choice, `\rm` has been known to tex syntax checkers editor highlighting etc for nearly 40 years defining a new command of the same name but different syntax will confuse everything, not just me.

Comment: Your restriction has moved from strange, to simply wrong. `xltabular` uses `tabularx` which is based on `array` by the same author, me:-) so you are loading `array`.

Comment: Ok, sorry, i didn't test enough the array package and I was skeptical about it and the incompatibilities, I'm probably going to delete this question, but now that you are here, the creator of `xltabular`, can I ask you how to move the title of a section to a new page if an `xltabular` environment inmediatly breaks page. I mean that there is some cases were the title of the section is in the last line of the page and the `xltabular` starts in a new page and it looks weird. Thank you for you LaTeX colaborations

Comment: it shouldn't happen, but if it does, simplest is probably to just put `\clearpage` before the `\section`

Answer (score 0):

This might be better syntax-wise, but I don't think you have too many of these constructions in your document. Only normal sized cells are supported.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{report}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\NewDocumentCommand{\undermat}{mm}{%
  \vphantom{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}%
  \smash{\,\underbrace{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}_{#1}\,}%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\overmat}{mm}{%
  \vphantom{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}%
  \smash{\,\overbrace{\begin{matrix}#2\end{matrix}}^{#1}\,}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set_eq:NN \Replicate \prg_replicate:nn
\ExplSyntaxOff

\NewDocumentCommand{\fixunder}{m}{%
  \vphantom{%
    \underbrace{\begin{matrix}\Replicate{#1-1}{\\}\end{matrix}}_{\mathstrut}%
  }%
}
\NewDocumentCommand{\fixover}{m}{%
  \vphantom{%
    \overbrace{\begin{matrix}\Replicate{#1-1}{\\}\end{matrix}}^{\mathstrut}%
  }%
}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1-4]
\[
\fixunder{3}\fixover{3}
\left(
  \undermat{A}{
    2 & 3 & 1 \\
    1 & 0 & 1 \\
    5 & 4 & 6
  }
\;\middle|\;
  \undermat{I}{
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 0
   }
\right)
\xrightarrow[\textrm{Jordan}]{\textrm{Gauss}}
\left(
  \overmat{I}{
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 1 & 0 \\
    0 & 0 & 1
  }
\;\middle|\;
  \overmat{A^{-1}}{
    4/7 &  2 & -3/7 \\
    1/7 & -1 &  1/7 \\
   -4/7 & -1 &  3/7
  }
\right)
\]
\lipsum[1][1-4]

\end{document}
```

Note the `\fixover` and `\fixunder` commands that take as argument the number of rows that should be considered.

Avoid `$$` in LaTeX, see [Why is \[ ... \] preferable to $$ ... $$?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503). In the sense that you should ***never*** use it inside `document` (there are a few cases in which `$$...$$` is useful in defining commands or environments).

[image]

In this *particular* case, when the line before the display is short, you migh avoid `\fixover{3}` to get

[image]